# Replace the android incoming call dialog screen with flutter dialog screen

Tags: flutter

I want to replace the android incoming call dialog screen with flutter dialog screen. when we receive the calls from others, flutter app should listen the incoming call and show the details in dialog screen as same as native android screen. Please help on this.

tried phone state. but it is not working as expected

Comment: hmmm, Why don't try  to get/make one a function on native if you able to get incoming call then at flutter side you have an appstate listener if that function from native incoming call which is notif lets say it,Then trigger the flutter screen if you able to receive some any notif signal or some trigger to do it

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share more details, how to do it in flutter application?